# PL/SQL Function Logic

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

So recently i've started experimenting with databases and i'm still new and although i'm getting several examples to do with **functions**..I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my logic.

So I have a **table** called "**tutorial**" and i'm trying to just match a row from within the table to the logged in user. I'm sure i've set the logged in user to **v_user** right..so it's just the logic in the following code I think.

```
if v_emp_no != 0 and (select tutor_emp_no into v_tutor_emp_no from tutorial where
lower(tutor_emp_no) = v_user) then

 -- Employee is a Tutor
 is_tutor := 1;
end if;
```

Of course this is not the full function :)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! :)

** EDIT **

This is the **policy** that works in the example given to me under a created user 'sec_admin' using oe owned tables whereas doesn't work in my given **sys** role user named 'dummy'.

```
begin
dbms_rls.add_policy('oe',
                    'enrol',
                    'accesscontrol_enrol',
                    'sys',
                    'f_policy_enrol',
                    policy_type => dbms_rls.context_sensitive);
end;
/
```

Should i change the '**oe**' to '**dummy**' or '**sys**'? The table I want this policy to work for is called **enrol** and it's a table that **i've created** through my **dummy** user. Thanks again!

Comment: The first parameter to `dbms_rls.add_policy` is the owner of the table, so yes you should put in `'dummy'` if that is the owner of the table `enrol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot specify a `SQL` inside `IF` statement, so let's first query and then check the result in the `IF`

```
select MAX(tutor_emp_no) into v_tutor_emp_no from tutorial where
lower(tutor_emp_no) = v_user;

if v_emp_no != 0 and v_tutor_emp_no is NOT NULL then

 -- Employee is a Tutor
 is_tutor := 1;
end if;
```

The `MAX()` is just to return `NULL` if no records found.!

Comment: Oh that makes sense as to why I cannot find anything about it..so we cannot have an SQL query inside an IF statement. Thanks heaps :)! I'll test to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working! :) 
@OracleUser If I have any follow up questions, may I ask them to you?

Comment: I would like to test out the Function and see if it's working right. So far the function is being created without error. The example given to invoke the policy and done through the dbms_dls.add_policy command but when I try it I get a "table or view does not exist" error. I'll edit the main post with the policy so you can see where i've gone wrong. :)

Comment: I've updated the initial post. Any help..well you'd be a life saver! :)

Comment: are you able to `desc` the table and the `enrol` table exists in `sys` schema?

Comment: I can definitely `desc` the `enrol` table. I don't know what a schema is. But when I created the table, it was through a "**dummy**" user connecting as `sysdba`.

Comment: `select owner,table_name from all_tables where table_name='ENROL'` . here `owner` is the schema name.

Comment: Oh I see! Wow that's handy. Thanks for that! :)
Two results came through: `DBASTUDENT` and `SYS`. Does that mean both `DBASTUDENT` and `SYS` are owners of the same table? Because to my understanding there cannot be two tables with the same name.

Comment: Across different Schema(Owner), table names can be different!!

Comment: Thank you OracleUser. It's working! :) Hope I wasn't too much of a hassle!

Comment: Not at all. Good Luck!

Comment: Is there a way to drop or remove the policy that i've just added?

Comment: You need [DBMS_RLS.DROP_POLICY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_rls.htm#i998159) ??

Comment: I have a question about function logic that i'm not really understanding. This line here: `out_string := out_string||'or student_no = '||v_student_no||' ';`. I have no idea what i'm reading. Reckon you could guide me through it? :) Thank you :))

Comment: you are appending `or student_no = some_number` to your existing string `out_string`

Comment: So basically, will it filter out every other record unless `student_no = v_student_no`? If you have Skype or an email I could show you what i'm trying to do, if you'd like to take helping me a step further hehe :P

Comment: Or actually, if you can..look at my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896887/oracle-function-not-working Would be very much appreciated OracleUser!

Comment: I've added you on Skype. If you could hop on, that would be helpful. :) Unless we can start a chat here between us?