# Oracle - Function not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Oracle - Function not working

So I got no idea what i'm doing wrong. I've been at it for hours and i'd really appreciate some help.

So basically I have 2 tables, one is called `student` and it's a list of students with `student_no` being the primary key, and the other table called `enrol` which basically has the list of programs that the student is enrolled into.

So i've written a function that compares the logged in student's username, which in this case is the `student_no`, to the list of students and makes sure that the logged in user is a student. Then it compares the `student_no` with the `enrol` table to seek out any programs the user is enrolled into. So that in essence when I `SELECT * FROM yaser.enrol` (the table owner is yaser) I should see only a few records from the enrol list. Instead I get the error: `failed to execute policy function`.

Here is my Function:

```
-- Create policy function to be called when 'ENROL' table is accessed
create or replace function f_policy_enrol (schema in varchar2, tab in varchar2)
-- Function will return a string that is used as a WHERE clause                       
return varchar2
as
 v_student_no     varchar2(10);
 is_student       number:=0;
 v_user           varchar2(100);
 out_string       varchar2(400) default '1=2 ';

begin
  -- get session user
  v_user := lower(sys_context('userenv','session_user'));

  -- Is the user a student?
  begin
    select student_no into v_student_no from student where lower(student_no) = v_user;
    is_student:=1;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
    v_student_no := 0;
  end;

  -- If it's a student, then they are only allowed to see their record only.
  if is_student = 1 then
     out_string := out_string||'or student_no = '||v_student_no||' ';
  end if;

  return out_string;
end;
/
```

And this is the Policy that I invoke:

```
begin
dbms_rls.add_policy('yaser',
                    'enrol',
                    'accesscontrol_enrol',
                    'yaser',
                    'f_policy_enrol',
                    policy_type => dbms_rls.context_sensitive);
end;
/
```

As said before..I'm not sure where i'm going wrong. Whether in the policy or function. ANY HELP would be greatly appreciated! If you have any questions, i'm happy to answer just as soon as I get some free time at work!

Thanks in advance!

Yaser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the data type of the `student_no` column?  The column name implies that it is a `NUMBER`.  But the fact that you're calling `lower` on it and comparing it to the session user implies that it is a `VARCHAR2`.

Assuming `student_no` is a `VARCHAR2`, one problem is that your predicate is missing single quotes around the value.  If `v_student_no` is, for example, "jcave", your `out_string` would be

```
1=2 or student_no = jcave
```

Since "jcave" isn't quoted, Oracle assumes that it must be an identifier so it looks for a column in the table named `jcave`.  Finding no such column, it throws an error.  You'd have more luck if you put single quotes around the string

```
out_string := out_string||'or student_no = '''||v_student_no||''' ';
```

There may be additional errors as well.  Have you tried calling the function manually to see exactly what it returns?  If you had called the function manually when `session_user` was set to "jcave", you should have seen the result that is lacking the single quotes.  If you copy and paste the return value and add that to the end of your `SELECT` statement, you'd see the error straight away.  You can also query `v$vpd_policy` to see the particular policy predicate(s) that have been added to a particular SQL statement if you want to avoid calling the function manually-- this is very useful when you're trying to debug VPD problems with session state that you can't easily reproduce.

Comment: You are right. It is a `VARCHAR(10)`. Although even after applying your fix, it's giving me the same error. I'm very new to Oracle and honestly I just learnt what you meant by calling the function manually. I did that, same error. Anything else? :) Thanks heaps for your input.

Comment: @YaserSleiman - Are you saying that when you call the function manually `select f_policy_enrol( null, null ) from dual` that you are getting a VPD related error?  That seems highly unlikely.

Comment: Oh sorry! I misunderstood. I thought you meant `out_string := out_string||'or student_no = '''||v_student_no||''' ' FROM yaser.enrol;`. Umm, in this case, I'm sorry, I don't know how to call a function manually. :(

Comment: @YaserSleiman - Run the `SELECT` statement I posted in my last comment.  Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry again. I get a `"F_POLICY_ENROL": invalid identifier` error.

Comment: @YaserSleiman - What schema are you creating the function in?  What user are you logged in as when you run the function?  Are you logged in as a different user than the one you used to create the function?

Comment: Yes it's definitely a different user. I created it under a user `yaser` and am trying to run the function through a different user `s147`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47917/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-yaser-sleiman)

Comment: Justin could you please re-enter the chat? Thank you! :)