# Oracle Procedure - Return all rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have several tables and I've created different roles to go with different users so that each can access a portion of the tables.

Right now, whenever I try to `SELECT * FROM yaser.enrol;` with a coordinator who is meant to see everything, I get the error `numeric or value error: character to number conversion error` which points to the lines where i'm querying the `employee_no` to determine the employee role.

Theres 4 overall types of users: student, tutor, lecturer, coordinator.

EDIT ** Added all code.

```
-- Create policy function to be called when ‘ENROL’ table is accessed under user Yaser.
create or replace function f_policy_enrol (schema in varchar2, tab in varchar2)

return varchar2
as
  v_emp_no            varchar2(10);
  v_student_no        varchar2(10);
  v_tutor_emp_no      varchar2(10);
  v_lecturer_emp_no   varchar2(10); 
  v_coord_emp_no      varchar2(10);
  is_tutor            number:=0;
  is_lecturer         number:=0;
  is_coordinator      number:=0;
  is_student          number:=0;
  is_employee         number:=0;
  v_program_code      varchar2(10);
  v_user              varchar2(100);
  out_string          varchar2(400) default '1=2 ';
 -- The return value will be out_string. '1=2' means 'Nothing to access'. 

begin
  -- get session user
  v_user := lower(sys_context('userenv','session_user'));

  -- Is the user a student?
  begin
    SELECT student_no INTO v_student_no FROM student WHERE lower(student_no) = v_user;
    is_student:=1;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
    v_student_no := 0;
  end;

  -- Is the user an employee?
  begin
    SELECT emp_no INTO v_emp_no FROM employee WHERE lower(emp_no) = v_user;
    is_employee:=1;
  exception
    when no_data_found then
    v_emp_no := 0;
  end;

  -- Query the employee number to determine role. 
  -- If Tutor.
  SELECT MAX(tutor_emp_no) INTO v_tutor_emp_no FROM tutorial WHERE lower(tutor_emp_no) = v_user;
  -- If Lecturer.
  SELECT MAX(course_coord_emp_no) INTO v_lecturer_emp_no FROM course WHERE lower(course_coord_emp_no) = v_user;
  -- If Coordinator.
  SELECT MAX(prog_coord_emp_no) into v_coord_emp_no FROM program WHERE lower(prog_coord_emp_no) = v_user;

  -- Get role of the employee if the user is an employee.
  if v_emp_no != 0 and v_tutor_emp_no is NOT NULL then
     -- Employee is a Tutor.
     is_tutor := 1;
  elsif v_emp_no != 0 and v_lecturer_emp_no is NOT NULL then
     -- Employee is Lecturer.
     is_lecturer := 1;
  elsif v_emp_no != 0 and v_coord_emp_no is NOT NULL then
     -- Employee is Coordinator.
     is_coordinator := 1;
  end if;

  -- Create the string to be used as the WHERE clause.
  if is_student = 1 then
     -- Students are allowed to see their orders only.
     out_string := out_string||'or student_no = '''||v_student_no||''' ';
  end if;

  if is_tutor = 1 then
     -- Tutors are allowed to see enrolments of students that they tutor.
----     out_string := out_string||'or student_no in (select student_no from tutorial where tutor_emp_no = '||v_tutor_emp_no||') ';
---- NOT WORKING.
     out_string := out_string||'or student_no in (select student_no from tutorial where lower(tutor_emp_no) = v_tutor_emp_no) ';

  end if;

  if is_coordinator = 1 then
     -- The coordinator is allowed to see all records in ENROL (WHERE 1=1 or anything) means all rows.
     out_string := out_string||'or 1=1 ';
  end if;

  return out_string;
end;
/
```

These are the tables i'm referencing:

```
CREATE TABLE course
(
    course_code varchar(10),
    course_title varchar(50),
    course_coord_emp_no varchar(10),
    primary key (course_code)
);
```

And - all employees:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    emp_no varchar(10),
    name   varchar(100)
);
```

All other tables are basically the same - `VARCHARS`

Any help would be good! :)
Yaser

Comment: please show the whole procedure and the input and the error

Comment: 'It's failing' is not a valid error message. Please do show your code; presumably you're building up `out_string` to execute as dynamic SQL, maybe opening a ref cursor? Based on the tiny bit you've shown my guess would be that you need a space before the `or` in `' or 1=1 '`; or that you have a parentheses problem. But there's way to little here to be able to give a decent answer.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Sorry guys, please see my edit in the initial post!

Comment: That won't compile... do you get a compilation error?

Comment: You'll want to go through the same debugging steps we talked about last night in your earlier question on this same function.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896887/oracle-function-not-working  Run the function directly via a SELECT statement.  Make sure that the function is returning a valid predicate before you go using it to create a VPD function.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes a little more sense. Although the logic seems to be that a known student can only see their own data, and anyone else - based just on the `student_no` check, so let's hope that's robust enough - can see everything?

Comment: Well, it's just one other type of user that can see everything - Coordinator. But honestly the reason i've started this thread is just to find out how to compare two strings via `out_string := out_string||'or 1=1 ‘;` instead of two numbers. Although I'm actually going through the debugging steps that you taught me for another problem i'm facing. Hehe. :)

Comment: @JustinCave, After running through the debugging steps. I landed at `numeric or value error: character to number conversion error` at this line: `SELECT MAX(course_coord_emp_no) INTO v_lecturer_emp_no FROM course WHERE lower(course_coord_emp_no) = v_user;` although i've read it again and again, everything seems to be varchar. Am I missing something?

Comment: It has something to do with the `MAX()` doesn't it?

Comment: @YaserSleiman - Well, that `SELECT` statement doesn't appear in the code you posted.  So it appears that the code you posted is rather different from the code you're actually using.  Is `course_coord_emp_no` a `VARCHAR2` column?  Is `v_lecturer_emp_no` declared as a `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: @JustinCave They are both declared as VARCHAR(10) just like the `student_no` we were working with and that worked. The only difference I see is the `2` in `VARCHAR2` and the `MAX()`. I wouldn't think it's the `2` solely because `student_no` is the same and it worked.

Comment: @YaserSleiman - Post the actual code that you're using and the definitions of the tables you're referencing.  While you're editing the question, please include the error number and line number from your comment.

Comment: @JustinCave, Done. I just felt uncomfortable posting everything.

Comment: You still haven't shown the table definitions. Aside from whatever number field is erroring, you're missing a space at the end of the `or student_no in()` line; and `v_tutor_no` isn't going to be in-scope for whatever consumes the final string (VPD)' you'd need to concatenate the actual value of that.

Comment: @YaserSleiman - According to your most recent update, you're getting a  "character to number conversion error" when you do a `SELECT * from yaser.enrol`.  Are you sure about that?  That error would potentially make sense if you were just calling the function directly.  If you're querying the `enrol` table, VPD won't raise an error that points at a line in the policy function.

Comment: @JustinCave, Nono. I got that error through calling the function directly.
@AlexPoole, Table definitions - Done. Why won't `v_tutor_no` be in scope? It's supposed to return a 4 character `student_no`, but I've yet to get that working.

Comment: @AlexPoole, Fixed the space at the end of the line but still doesn't seem to work. So far, only the student user has worked. The 3 employees have all returned a `failed to execute policy function`.
And the `Error` Line from before was 51.

Comment: Hey guys, just letting you know that it's 8:20am. I've been at it all night. I'm going to go get some sleep. I'll wake up in the morning and check if you've replied as soon as I wake up. I can't stress enough how thankful I am to both of you. :) Goodnight!

Comment: @JustinCave, Did you find anything?

Comment: Through commenting and uncommenting, I rounded down the error to the line `elsif v_emp_no != 0 and v_coord_emp_no is NOT NULL then`. This was throwing the `numeric or value error: character to number conversion error` error.

Comment: Got it. How stupid of me. `v_emp_no` cannot be compared to a 0!

Answer (score 1):

The question has evolved a *lot* and much of this answer was about a missing `end if` that wasn't relevant to your actual code. To go actually go back to your *original* question, using `or 1=1` as a catch-all is OK even though the other branch of the `if` if comparing strings - it makes no difference at all. If you really did want to compare strings you can do the same thing:

```
'or ''x''=''x'' '
```

... or

```
'or v_user=v_user '
```

But you can't compare empty strings as you seem to show in a comment. An empty string, `''`,  is the same as `null` in Oracle , and you can't equate anything to `null`, even itself. (The previous check would fail if `v_user` was `null`, for the same reason). So another possibility would be:

```
'or null is null '
```

Note that the comparator here is `is`, not `=`.

None of which addresses why you get the VPD error, as all of those are equivalent really - they all always evaluate to true and it doesn't matter which you use. Anything that effectively ends up as `or true` would work exactly the same; just a shame that Oracle SQL doesn't understand booleans like that. The datatypes being compared in any other clauses are irrelevant to this clause.

You need to see what the function is actually returning in both cases, verify it's what you expect, and verify that it works as a restriction when you query the table the VPD is against directly.

Comment: Thanks for that but it compiles fine, the problem is that I got the code `out_string := out_string||'or 1=1 ‘;` from an example that was using numbers to return whereas i'm using varchars. Don't I need to change the `'or 1=1 '` to better fit for varchars?

Comment: Also, yep the single-quotes did that when copying. Thanks for the heads up though :)

Comment: You're comparing two number in that clause - `1=1`. It doesn't matter that a different clause is comparing strings. I added a note to check your quotes too. The code you posted is not valid. And how are you calling;using this? It would be worth executing it stand-alone to verify that it runs and shows you what you expect; `select f_policy_enrol(user, 'x') from dual`, say, since `tab` doesn't seem to be used?

Comment: The code I gave is different to the one i'm using. I understand that this doesn't compile and it has errors and such but that's not what I started this thread for. I just gave this code as an example. My real and only question is basically how to compare two strings. As you said that the `1=1` is comparing two numbers in that clause but i'd like to know how to compare two strings. I've tried `out_string := out_string||'or ''=''` but that didn't work. Please take no offence at all! :)

Comment: You edited the question to add the code you were asked for, so showing something else is wasting everyone's time a bit. You are getting an error, so something is wrong in your code. If you won't show us your code we can't tell you what that is. Why do you want to compare two strings at all, when `1=1` would be fine?

Comment: Oh really? `1=1` would do fine on strings too? Honestly I didn't want to put the whole code here and have to explain it all and I really thought that asking this question would be nice and quick. I learnt from that mistake! Hehe